# Code Templates in Flash Builder 4.5 don't work?

Tags: flash-builder, flashbuilder4

I would like to customize the way FB generates new classes, interfaces, code snippets... Nothing major, white space, indentation, things like that, to match my coding style. I follow the instructions on this page:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/flashbuilder45-coding-enhancements.html

But nothing really changes... any insights?

Comment: i'm having the exact same problem.anyone? bueller?

Answer (score 0):

Hm.  For some reason, editing templates in Preferences>Flash Builder>Editors>Code Templates>ActionScript doesn't seem to change much, at least in my Flash Builder workflow (create new classes via New>ActionScript Class, create getters/setters via Source>Generate Getter/Setter, etc).

However, editing the templates in Preferences>Flash Builder>Editors>Code Templates>Flash Builder *does* work.  Stumbled across that [here](http://www.danvega.org/blog/2011/6/13/Flash-Builder-Code-Templates).

Yay for complexity and building on top of Eclipse!  Oy.